# Difference between <= and >= in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Can someone please tell me the difference between <= and >= in VHDL?I know its greater than/less than or equal to sign.Can someone be precise and explain with a code of line how the execution takes place.I know usually for signal assignment we use <= but for example in state machines or whenever we use WHEN >= pops out.Can someone please tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference writing these in if-statements and elsewhere.

When using these in if-statements a mathematical operation is taking place. As you wrote a comparision is done, checking if value is great-or-equal, smaller-or-equal to the value you compare to.

When writing codes outside of the if-statements this are part of the VHDL syntax and has no mathematical meaning, it is just how the languagre is constructed.

`signal_a <= signal_b  -- Assign signal B to signal A`

`-- When something is A then do whats is inside when block
case something is
   when A =>
      -- Do some stuff
   when others =>
      -- Do other stuff
end case;`

Comment: question is about `>=` not `=>`.

Comment: Interpreted >= as a typo since >= isn't correct syntax in the context described in the question...